# Why 'pca' in Matlab doesn't give orthogonal principal components?

Tags: matlab, pca, orthogonal, principal-components

Why using `pca` in Matlab, I cannot get the orthogonal principal component matrix

For example:

```
A=[3,1,-1;2,4,0;4,-2,-5;11,22,20];

A =

    3     1    -1
    2     4     0
    4    -2    -5
   11    22    20



>> W=pca(A)

W =

    0.2367    0.9481   -0.2125
    0.6731   -0.3177   -0.6678
    0.7006   -0.0150    0.7134


>> PCA=A*W

PCA =

    0.6826    2.5415   -2.0186
    3.1659    0.6252   -3.0962
   -3.9026    4.5028   -3.0812
   31.4249    3.1383   -2.7616
```

Here, every column is a principle component. So,

```
>> PCA(:,1)'*PCA(:,2)

ans =

   84.7625
```

But the principle component matrix hasn't mutually orthogonal components.

I checked some materials, it said they are not only uncorrelated, but strictly orthogonal. But I can't get the desired result. Can somebody tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting confused between the representation of `A` in the PCA feature space and the principal components. `W` are the principal components, and they will indeed be orthogonal.

Check that `W(:,1).'*W(:,2) = 5.2040e-17`, `W(:,1).'*W(:,3) = -1.1102e-16`  -- indeed orthogonal

What you are *trying* to do is to transform the data (i.e. `A`) in the PCA feature space. You should mean center the data first and then multiply by the principal components as follows.

```
% A_PCA = (A-repmat(mean(A),4,1))*W
% A more efficient alternative to the above command
A_PCA = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))*W
% verify that it is correct by comparing it with `score` - i.e. the PCA representation 
% of A given by MATLAB.
[W, score] = pca(A); % mean centering will occur inside pca
(score-(A-repmat(mean(A),4,1))*W) % elements are of the order of 1e-14, hence equal.
```

Comment: It's more efficient to use `bsxfun` than `repmat` for the mean centering: `A_PCA = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A))*W`

Comment: Oh, without mean centering, that's what I missed! Thanks!

Comment: And the representation of A in PCA feature space, i.e., the `score` is also orthogonal.